# Derivation of Formula for Power

Tags: circuit-analysis

The power dissipated by a resistor can be written as $$V(t)I(t)$$ where both the voltage and current can vary with time. I don't understand why the formula is not
$$\frac{dW}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt} (Vq) = \frac{dV}{dt}q+\frac{dq}{dt}V=\frac{dV}{dt}q+VI$$
Where W is the work done by the resistor. I've seen it derived as $$\frac{dW}{dt}=\frac{dW}{dq}\frac{dq}{dt}=V\frac{dq}{dt}$$
But what makes the first expression incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See pages 1-2 of this 22 page reference:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/03_kirchhoff1.pdf

Potential:

$$V = \frac{dW}{dq}$$

this is also called voltage it is the work required to move a positive test charge from a specified point to another specified point through a conservative electric field. Note time is not a factor in the definition of work done in a conservative field.

Current:

$$I = \frac{dq}{dt}$$

is equal to the amount of charge q passing through a cross-section per
second.

The result for electrical power development at an instant of time is shown in your question. The chain rule does not apply here because the definition of voltage/potential and current are already in the forms given. The potential is considered constant at each instant of time even if it varies from instant to instant and the current is the amount of charge moving at each instant even if it varies from instant to instant. Therefore power development is defined at each instant.

Comment: thanks for your response, I still have two questions about the derivation. 

Firstly, is the reason W can't be written as Vq is that the charge may vary over the integral, meaning it can't be factored out as a constant? Secondly, does V=dW/dq just follow from using Leibnitz's rule and differentiating the integral definition of work with respect to q?

Also, could you elaborate on the potential being considered constant ("The potential is considered constant...at each instance")? If in the end result the voltage is a function of time (as it often is), isn't the time derivative non-zero?

Comment: The fundamental definition of work is force acting through a distance in a straight line. Potential V = dW/dq is the potential at any moment of time which means the work to move a quantity of charge q across the potential V at that moment would be W = Vq. However if the potential varies over time the power varies at each instant of time and then integrate to find the total amount of work performed for a process. You need to take the physical definitions as primary and the math as secondary to set up the differential equations in a given case study.